# multiple actions for broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have registered one broadcast receiver in manifest file for  connectivity change..It works fine whenever the network changes, `onReceive()` gets called. But when I launch my app and there is internet ; since there is no change in network; receiver does not get called. I want this receiver to get called for the first launch of the app..

My idea is to add one more action to `BroadcastReceievr`, is this good idea? and whenever connectivity change action gets called I want to unregister the launcher action intent..

What can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple filters like this:

```
    IntentFilter inf = new IntentFilter();
    inf.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    inf.addAction("app_launch");

    registerReceiver(receiver, inf);
```

And when you launch your app in onCreate you can send a broadcast

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("app_launch");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: But when the network changes there will be two receivers listening to two different intents..I want to unregister app_launch action once the network change action gets called..I have trouble with this

Comment: No there will be one receiver listening to two actions it will get called every time you broad cast app_launch and when network changes

Comment: i have started the alarm manager from the broadcast reciever..But i will have to unregister the receiver when i destroy the activity in this case.

Comment: you can actually keep a boolean in sharedpreferences "isFirstLaunch" and before you broadcast app_launch just check if it is set to true and set it to false that way you well only be broadcasting app_launch once.

Comment: also no need to un-register your receiver as now it will only be called when connectivity changes